# Reading application preferences as Integer in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am developing a sample application where I have "ListPreference" like this:

```xml
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="180"
    android:entries="@array/pref_sync_frequency_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_sync_frequency_values"
    android:key="sync_frequency"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_sync_frequency"/>
```

and I bind it to the array of integers like this:

```xml
<string name="pref_title_sync_frequency">Sync frequency</string>
<string-array name="pref_sync_frequency_titles">
    <item>15 minutes</item>
    <item>30 minutes</item>
    <item>1 hour</item>
    <item>3 hours</item>
    <item>6 hours</item>
    <item>12 hours</item>
    <item>24 hours</item>
    <item>Never</item>
</string-array>
<integer-array name="pref_sync_frequency_values">
    <item>15</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>60</item>
    <item>180</item>
    <item>360</item>
    <item>720</item>
    <item>1440</item>
    <item>-1</item>
</integer-array>
```

From what I understand the persistence of the preference is provided by the PreferenceFragment from which I extend the fragment where I have the ListPreference.  I don't have any extra code except for what was provided when I was creating a Setting activity in Android Studio:

```java
public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
```

Now the problem is that when I try to read the preference, I want to read it as integers like this:

```java
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
return sharedPref.getInt("sync_frequency", 0);
```

But I get this exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: **java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer**

I can read the preference as a sting and then convert to int, but I would expect the preference already stored as an Integer since I bind it to an array of integers.  Why is it stored as a String and is it possible to store it as an Integer?

Comment: If you store it manually you can do it the way you want. But if using a ListPreference it will be stored as a String. You will have to parse it back to integer

Comment: Yes, I want to see if that can be done "out of the box".

Comment: As it is implemented right now I would say you can't. However, what you can actually do is to implement your own `ListPreference` that works with integer values